# Recursively print all json elements and nested elements using gson

Tags: java, json, recursion, gson

My program currently gets a response from an api which returns an extensive json script, usually around 400 lines or more. Within this JSON there are well over 20 elements, of which only about 2 are needed for other functions, the rest just needs to printed.
I have tried to make classes for each element but it became excessive, especially when the elements had different variations, and so i was told a recursive approach would be better suited. My current attempt involves using gson, although I find myself using instanceof in order to determine whether the next json element can be mapped using gson.

My JSON script looks as follows:

```
{
  "id": "fox",
  "metadata": {
    "operation": "retrieve",
    "provider": "Oxford University Press",
    "schema": "RetrieveEntry"
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "fox",
      "language": "en-gb",
      "lexicalEntries": [
        {
          "derivatives": [
            {
              "id": "foxlike",
              "text": "foxlike"
            }
          ],
          "entries": [
            {
              "etymologies": [
                "Old English, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch vos and German Fuchs"
              ],
              "pronunciations": [
                {
                  "audioFile": "https://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/fox_gb_1.mp3",
                  "dialects": [
                    "British English"
                  ],
                  "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                  "phoneticSpelling": "fɒks"
                }
              ],
              "senses": [
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "a carnivorous mammal of the dog family with a pointed muzzle and bushy tail, proverbial for its cunning."
                  ],
                  "domainClasses": [
                    {
                      "id": "mammal",
                      "text": "Mammal"
                    }
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0384950.006",
                  "notes": [
                    {
                      "text": "Vulpes and three other genera, family Canidae: several species, including the red fox and the arctic fox",
                      "type": "technicalNote"
                    }
                  ],
                  "semanticClasses": [
                    {
                      "id": "canid",
                      "text": "Canid"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shortDefinitions": [
                    "carnivorous mammal"
                  ],
                  "subsenses": [
                    {
                      "definitions": [
                        "the fur of a fox."
                      ],
                      "domainClasses": [
                        {
                          "id": "mammal",
                          "text": "Mammal"
                        }
                      ],
                      "id": "m_en_gbus0384950.010",
                      "notes": [
                        {
                          "text": "mass noun",
                          "type": "grammaticalNote"
                        }
                      ],
                      "semanticClasses": [
                        {
                          "id": "fur",
                          "text": "Fur"
                        }
                      ],
                      "shortDefinitions": [
                        "fur of fox"
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "synonyms": [
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "Reynard"
                    }
                  ],
                  "thesaurusLinks": [
                    {
                      "entry_id": "fox",
                      "sense_id": "t_en_gb0006011.001"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "a cunning or sly person"
                  ],
                  "examples": [
                    {
                      "text": "a wily old fox"
                    }
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0384950.013",
                  "semanticClasses": [
                    {
                      "id": "disliked_person",
                      "text": "Disliked_Person"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shortDefinitions": [
                    "cunning or sly person"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "a sexually attractive woman."
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0384950.015",
                  "regions": [
                    {
                      "id": "north_american",
                      "text": "North_American"
                    }
                  ],
                  "registers": [
                    {
                      "id": "informal",
                      "text": "Informal"
                    }
                  ],
                  "semanticClasses": [
                    {
                      "id": "attractive_female",
                      "text": "Attractive_Female"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shortDefinitions": [
                    "sexually attractive woman"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "language": "en-gb",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "noun",
            "text": "Noun"
          },
          "text": "fox"
        },
        {
          "derivatives": [
            {
              "id": "foxlike",
              "text": "foxlike"
            }
          ],
          "entries": [
            {
              "grammaticalFeatures": [
                {
                  "id": "transitive",
                  "text": "Transitive",
                  "type": "Subcategorization"
                }
              ],
              "pronunciations": [
                {
                  "audioFile": "https://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/fox_gb_1.mp3",
                  "dialects": [
                    "British English"
                  ],
                  "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                  "phoneticSpelling": "fɒks"
                }
              ],
              "senses": [
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "baffle or deceive (someone)"
                  ],
                  "examples": [
                    {
                      "text": "the abbreviation foxed me completely"
                    }
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0384950.017",
                  "registers": [
                    {
                      "id": "informal",
                      "text": "Informal"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shortDefinitions": [
                    "baffle or deceive"
                  ],
                  "subsenses": [
                    {
                      "definitions": [
                        "behave in a cunning or sly way"
                      ],
                      "examples": [
                        {
                          "text": "to his mind everybody was dodging and foxing"
                        }
                      ],
                      "id": "m_en_gbus0384950.023",
                      "notes": [
                        {
                          "text": "no object",
                          "type": "grammaticalNote"
                        }
                      ],
                      "registers": [
                        {
                          "id": "dated",
                          "text": "Dated"
                        }
                      ],
                      "shortDefinitions": [
                        "behave in cunning or sly way"
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "synonyms": [
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "baffle"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "bewilder"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "mystify"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "bemuse"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "perplex"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "puzzle"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "confuse"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "confound"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "nonplus"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "disconcert"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "throw"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "throw off balance"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "disorientate"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "take aback"
                    },
                    {
                      "language": "en",
                      "text": "set thinking"
                    }
                  ],
                  "thesaurusLinks": [
                    {
                      "entry_id": "flummox",
                      "sense_id": "t_en_gb0005828.001"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "language": "en-gb",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "verb",
            "text": "Verb"
          },
          "text": "fox"
        }
      ],
      "type": "headword",
      "word": "fox"
    },
    {
      "id": "Fox",
      "language": "en-gb",
      "lexicalEntries": [
        {
          "entries": [
            {
              "inflections": [
                {
                  "grammaticalFeatures": [
                    {
                      "id": "plural",
                      "text": "Plural",
                      "type": "Number"
                    }
                  ],
                  "inflectedForm": "Fox"
                }
              ],
              "pronunciations": [
                {
                  "audioFile": "https://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/fox_gb_1.mp3",
                  "dialects": [
                    "British English"
                  ],
                  "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                  "phoneticSpelling": "fɒks"
                }
              ],
              "senses": [
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "a member of a North American people formerly living in southern Wisconsin, and now mainly in Iowa, Nebraska, and Kansas."
                  ],
                  "domainClasses": [
                    {
                      "id": "people",
                      "text": "People"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "amerindian",
                      "text": "Amerindian"
                    }
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0384960.006",
                  "semanticClasses": [
                    {
                      "id": "amerindian",
                      "text": "Amerindian"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shortDefinitions": [
                    "member of North American people"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "the Algonquian language of the Fox, now almost extinct."
                  ],
                  "domainClasses": [
                    {
                      "id": "language",
                      "text": "Language"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": "amerindian",
                      "text": "Amerindian"
                    }
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0384960.010",
                  "notes": [
                    {
                      "text": "mass noun",
                      "type": "grammaticalNote"
                    }
                  ],
                  "semanticClasses": [
                    {
                      "id": "amerindian_language",
                      "text": "Amerindian_Language"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shortDefinitions": [
                    "Algonquian language of Fox, now extinct"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "language": "en-gb",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "noun",
            "text": "Noun"
          },
          "text": "Fox"
        },
        {
          "entries": [
            {
              "pronunciations": [
                {
                  "audioFile": "https://audio.oxforddictionaries.com/en/mp3/fox_gb_1.mp3",
                  "dialects": [
                    "British English"
                  ],
                  "phoneticNotation": "IPA",
                  "phoneticSpelling": "fɒks"
                }
              ],
              "senses": [
                {
                  "definitions": [
                    "relating to the Fox or their language."
                  ],
                  "domainClasses": [
                    {
                      "id": "amerindian",
                      "text": "Amerindian"
                    }
                  ],
                  "id": "m_en_gbus0384960.013",
                  "shortDefinitions": [
                    "relating to Fox or their language"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "language": "en-gb",
          "lexicalCategory": {
            "id": "adjective",
            "text": "Adjective"
          },
          "text": "Fox"
        }
      ],
      "type": "headword",
      "word": "Fox"
    }
  ],
  "word": "fox"
}
```

If there are any edits I should make to my question please let me know, this is my first question here. Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
The output needs to be formatted neatly, so basically it must be line separated and should be displayed in an easy to read manner, but as well as this, some elements, such as synonyms, need to have their words hyperlinked so they must be identified separately. Hope this helps

Comment: Can you give an example of what an output should be for the given JSON? Do you intent to loop over some array or just get a specific object (from the JSON)?

Comment: Hey I just updated the question with an edit, hopefully it helps. I basically need to neatly format it without it looking like it was from the JSON, and some objects from the json need to be extracted separately as they have unique functions related to them.

Comment: Let me just make sure I understand what you need. You need to pretty print this JSON to a Java console output as well as getting the synonyms object for each entry and execute some Java code with it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I'm doing it through JavaFX so the output will be displayed in a window to the user, and synonyms will be hyperlinked, but essentially yes. Although I realised pretty printing keeps all the json formatting such as curly braces and quotations which is not what i want, unless i just did that wrong.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're really trying to achieve, but consider using `JsonElement` and its subclasses to make "perfect" JSON snapshots (mapping+deserialization can produce a "not perfect" JSON snapshot because of different deserialization rules) you can reuse multiple times, and have no need in custom mappings.

Comment: Yea I'm basically trying to neatly print everything within the JSON, but yea I've found that using gson disrupts the format of the JSON and so you can't treat it as a JSON after mapping and deserialising it. I decided to use simple JSON and dive into everything but have not found an effective way of recursively diving the deepest part of the json and printing the lines found.